# TypeError using the jwt-express package

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I just tried to work with the JWT-Express package for NodeJS in order to create a JWT token when a user wants to log in. Unfortunately, I receive a TypeError with the package.

Following my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var jwt = require('jwt-express');
app.use(jwt.init('secret'));

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    var user = {
        first: "Firstname",
        last: "Lastname",
        is_admin: true
    };

    // we are using cookies so the JWT is 
    // automatically stored for us
    var jwt = res.jwt({
        admin: user.is_admin,
        name: user.first + ' ' + user.last
    });

    // we now have access to the JWT Object
    console.log(jwt);

    // if we weren't using cookies, we could
    // now send the token to the client
    res.send(jwt.token);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

I verified that both the object `jwt` in line 3 and the call to `jwt.init` returns something unequal to undefined.

The error seems to stick somehow in the package internally. The system crashes even before the `GET` requests is being processed.

The error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'jwt-express' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/jwt-express/jwt-express.js:218:36)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/stuckenholz/auth/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Any ideas?

Best regards...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it happened that I had forgotten to include jwt options.
This solved it for me:

```
options = { cookies: false }
app.use(jwt.init('secret', options))
```

I am not using cookies

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `req.cookies` is empty at line 218:

```
token = req.cookies[this.options.cookie];
```

Don't forget to parse the cookies before initializing `jwt-express`:

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())
```

https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Comment: I think you checked the wrong package. You probably looked at express-jwt, which can only check existing tokens. I meant to use jwt-express which can also create them. When I look at the documentation of jwt-express at [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-express), I used the correct code.

Comment: @LosWochos You're right, the package name is a little bit confusing. I changed my answer, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Great! I did not realize the cookie-part. Thanks a lot. I found that you can disable storing the token in a cookie as well.